# How to save multiple plotly graphs in one document file using docx or python-docx package in python

Tags: python, plotly, docx, python-docx

I am plotting multiple graphs using the Plotly package. But I have to save those plots directly to a document file which I am unable to do. I tried with the Docx package but only one plot is getting saved. When I am trying to save another plot, it replaces the previous one. My code to save graphs in documents given below,

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
document = Document()
document.add_heading('Report',0)
document.add_picture('C:/Users/ABCD/Downloads/newplot.png', width=Inches(6))
document.save('C:/Users/ABCD/Downloads/report.docx')
```

Is there any option to update the document each time I save the plot? Also is there any way to automate the process as I will be using the code in a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new (blank) document each time, adding a picture to it, and then saving it with same name. So the behavior you're observing is the expected behavior; each iteration overwrites the prior version.

You will need to do a few things differently:

1. Only create a new document the first time.
2. On second and later iterations, open the saved document. Then when you add a picture to it you make it longer.

Probably better would be to:

1. Open a new document
2. Write all the required pictures to it.
3. Save the document.

But you'll need to decide what will work for your application.

Another possible approach would be:

1. Create a new, empty document and save it at the beginning of the editing session.
2. On each new chart, open that saved document, add the chart, and save the document.

You open an existing document with:

```
document = Document('C:/Users/ABCD/Downloads/report.docx')
```